# Assume $G \cong A \times B $ and also $G\cong A \times C$ ,such that $A,B,C$ are normal subgroups in $G$,show that $B\cong C$ .

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Assume $G \cong A \times B $ and also $G\cong A \times C$ ,such that $A,B,C$ are normal subgroups in $G$,show that $B\cong C$ .

I think it's a famous theorem,however I could not find any proof of that ,it would be highly appreciated if someone gives me a source for the proof or prove that here.

Comment: I think you can show that both $B$ and $C$ are necessarily isomorphic to the quotient group $G/A$.

Comment: This is false as stated. For one thing, you only have isomorphisms; $A$, $B$, and $C$ need not be subgroups of $G$, let alone normal subgroups. And for infinite groups, the conclusion may fail: $G=A=\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{Z}$, $B=\mathbb{Z}$, $C=\{e\}$. You really have to be very careful with the assumptions here, and you are not being careful.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin the poster explicitly stated that $A,B,$ and $C$ are normal subgroups of $G$?

Comment: @NoahSolomon: Fair enough; but they are given as isomorphisms; for all we know, the copies of $A$, $B$, and $C$ sitting inside the group intersect each other. It’s a mess as written, and in any case, the conclusion fails if the groups are not assumed to have some sort of finiteness condition. If equalities are meant, isomorphisms are not enough. If these are internal direct products, that needs to be explicitly stated.

Comment: @angryavian: that would only work if the compositions of the isomorphisms $A\times B\to G\to A\times C$ happens to map $A\times\{e\}$ to $A\times\{e\}$, and you have absolutely no warrant for assuming that is the case.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ah I see, that's a good point.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking about the cancellation property for the direct product of groups? I.e. when $A\oplus B\simeq A\oplus C$ implies $B\simeq C$? It is famously known to be false, e.g. for any nontrivial group $G$ we have $$\bigg(\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty G\bigg)\oplus G\simeq\bigg(\bigoplus_{i=1}^\infty G\bigg)\oplus 0$$ even though $G\not\simeq 0$ by assumption.

However it does hold in some cases, e.g. when $A$ is finite. You may want to read this classical paper: [R. Hirshon "On Cancellation in Groups"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2317133).